# What to look at next within the hs_err_pid###.log file?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

If I see something like the following in the hs_err_pid###.log file, is it a good indication of a leak or memory simply ran out?

The following shows the GC Heap History. There are 250 events and they all look the same with eden space at 100% used and ParOldGen is also maxed out.

```
GC Heap History (250 events):
Event: 603738.947 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=10735 (full 1042):
 PSYoungGen      total 245248K, used 220160K [0x00000000d5580000, 0x00000000e8680000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 220160K, 100% used [0x00000000d5580000,0x00000000e2c80000,0x00000000e2c80000)
  from space 25088K, 0% used [0x00000000e2c80000,0x00000000e2c80000,0x00000000e4500000)
  to   space 26112K, 0% used [0x00000000e6d00000,0x00000000e6d00000,0x00000000e8680000)
 ParOldGen       total 1398272K, used 1398162K [0x0000000080000000, 0x00000000d5580000, 0x00000000d5580000)
  object space 1398272K, 99% used [0x0000000080000000,0x00000000d5564b30,0x00000000d5580000)
 Metaspace       used 78830K, capacity 83683K, committed 146496K, reserved 1132544K
  class space    used 8021K, capacity 11589K, committed 62824K, reserved 1048576K
```

Could the following be related to the above? The GC Failed due to a lack of space?

```
Events (250 events):
Event: 603741.921 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation
Event: 603742.654 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation done
Event: 603742.655 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation
```

Does the Stack from the file seem to indicate the failure is happening within the JNI layer due to the reference to the libjvm.so file?

```
Stack: [0x00002b19adbe2000,0x00002b19adce2000],  sp=0x00002b19adce0970,  free space=1018k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x687782]
V  [libjvm.so+0x61061d]
V  [libjvm.so+0x474bb6]
V  [libjvm.so+0x612aff]
V  [libjvm.so+0xad56b7]
V  [libjvm.so+0xad3fc8]
V  [libjvm.so+0xad4499]
V  [libjvm.so+0xad48f1]
V  [libjvm.so+0x8beb82]
```

Here is the siginfo, but it doesn't tell me much :

```
 siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000040
```

Based on the above, does this fall into a leak or out of memory error?
What would be the next piece of the log file to research to further diagnose this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a good indication of a leak or memory simply ran out

No. If memory runs out JVM would throw `OutOfMemoryError`. Does not matter (heap or native). In case of jvm cannot allocate native memory needed via `malloc` or `mmap` returning NULL it will by understood be JVM and throw OOME either.

`SEGV` means a process tried to acess to an invalid memory location (e.g. 0 or a location does not belong to the process).

Without debug symbols of JVM it is difficult to say something specific.